# How can I add an element to a mapping array (mapping[])?

Tags: mapping

Remix accepts the following code and allows me to deploy the contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract bytes32array {



mapping(address => uint)[] balances;            


    function addBalance(address _address, uint _index, uint _amount) public {       
        balances[_index][_address] = _amount;                                       

    }


    function getBalance(address _address, uint8 _index) public view returns(uint) {
          return balances[_index][_address];

    }


}
```

However, when I try to use the "addBalance" function, I just get an error (both in Javascript VM and through web3/testrpc).  I get the error "VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode".  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, especially since the syntax is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your access is out of bounds. `balances` has a length of `0`, so `balances[x]` for any `x` will be an error. You can use `balances.push(...)` or `balances.length += 1` to extend the array.

Or use a mapping of mappings instead, if you don't intend to use consecutive IDs:

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256));
```

Comment: How do I use "balances.push" in this case?  I try pushing the address and amount, or just the address, but neither works.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can use `balances.push` at all here, since the thing you'd have to push would be a new `mapping` (and there's no defined copy from memory to storage of a `mapping`).